# What does 'plain codec' in logstash do?

Tags: logstash

I've just started out with logstash and I was studying about codecs, so please bear with me.

Searched on the internet about what the plain codec does, and couldn't quite get what I wanted. What exactly does the plain codec do? Would appreciate an answer which could explain in layman terms.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The codecs are additional treatment done on the content passing on the input and output plugins. For example, you can use the multiline codec on an input plugin to join multiple lines in one logstash event.

The plain codec is the codec used by default in the input and output plugins. **It does nothing** (which is logical since it's the default choice).